# SQLite-net-pcl not working properly on Android 7.0 (Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin, sqlite-net

SQLite-net-pcl seem's to work on all platforms except Android 7.0.

So far on Android 7.0 from a fresh install the application will crash due to an SQLException with the issue that it can't create a PK. If I uninstall the applications storage I.e. wipe the app from application settings, the app then works perfectly.

All other platforms seem to install instantly. See for youself https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.purewowstudio.fivestartips

I cannot seem to fix this. Worst of all, my iOS which shares a DB PCL doesn't load at all.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Code example:-

**Object**

```
using System;

namespace App.LocalObjects
{
[Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
public class LocalArticle
{

    [SQLite.PrimaryKey, SQLite.Column("articleObjectId")]
    public string objectId { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime updatedAt { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }

    public LocalArticle()
    {
        this.objectId = " ";
        this.Title = " ";
        this.Description = " ";
        this.Url = " ";
    }
}
}
```

**Database**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using SQLite;
using App.LocalObjects;

namespace App.DataLayer
{

public class Database
{
    static object locker = new object();
    public SQLiteConnection database;
    public string path;

    public Database(SQLiteConnection conn)
    {
        database = conn;
        database.CreateTable<LocalArticle>();
    }

public int SaveLocalArticleItem(LocalArticle item)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {

            LocalArticle article = database.Table<LocalArticle>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.objectId == item.objectId);

            if (article != null && article.objectId.Equals(item.objectId) && !article.updatedAt.Equals(item.updatedAt))
            {
                database.Update(item);

                return item.ID;
            } else {
                return database.Insert(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Code to initialize DB:**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Android.App;
using App.BusinessLayer.Managers;
using App.BusinessLayer.ParseObjects;
using App.Utils;
using Android.Content;
using Com.Nostra13.Universalimageloader.Core;
using Com.Nostra13.Universalimageloader.Core.Assist;
using Android.Graphics;
using Com.Nostra13.Universalimageloader.Cache.Memory.Impl;
using Com.OneSignal;
using Parse;
using SQLite;

namespace App.Droid
{
[Application(LargeHeap = true)]
public class App : Application
{

    public static App Current { get; private set; }
    public ModelManager modelManager { get; set; }
    private SQLiteConnection conn;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

public App(IntPtr handle, global::Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer)
        : base(handle, transfer)
    {
        Current = this;
    }

public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();

        SetupParse();
        SetupDB();
}

private void SetupParse()
    {
        ParseObject.RegisterSubclass<ParseArticle>();

        ParseClient.Initialize(new ParseClient.Configuration
        {
            ApplicationId = Constants.ParseApplicationID,
            Server = Constants.ParseServer
        });


    }

    private void SetupDB()
    {

        var sqliteFilename = Constants.DBName;
        string libraryPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(libraryPath, sqliteFilename);
        conn = new SQLiteConnection(path);

        modelManager = new ModelManager(conn);
}
```

Here's what my project is currently referencing:-

[image]

Comment: Try changing the `objectId` primary key to an `int` and then also add the `SQLite.AutoIncrement` annotation to it.

Comment: Hey @hvaughan3. I've managed to fix my issue. Not sure how at all but seem's to be working now. I managed to move on from this issue to another which has just been solved.

Comment: Nice! Check in your code and then don't ever touch it again so it won't break again ;)

Comment: Haha @hvaughan3. I'm making so many backups of this now it's working. I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Android N began actually enforcing rules around accessing the SQLite libraries that come with Android. Therefore any app (or app library) that was previously directly accessing SQLite without going through the special Java wrapper was already breaking the rules technically, the reason it was not a problem was because Android never really enforced those rules. Read more about that [here](http://ericsink.com/entries/sqlite_android_n.html)

Now that Android N does enforce those rules, it causes the crash to occur. I am guessing that you are using the SQLite.Net-PCL library for accessing your SQLite DB. If you look [here](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/issues/311) there is an open issue for that exact problem that the library creators never fixed.

We ran into the same issue and have since switched to the SQLite-Net-PCL library (notice the dash instead of the period) which works the exact same way and has an almost identical API. A link for that library can be found [here](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net).

Comment: Hi, yes I actually have moved to this library as well. Thats whats causing the issues. I was running SQLite.Net and it working but on Android N a popup kept appearing saying about sqlite.so. I then swapped to SQLite-net-plc and this has now killed both of my Android and iOS project. Seems strange that everyone else has theirs working. Im confused aa to wether Im missing something. Ive spent around 1 days worktrying to fix this but really stuck now.

Comment: @PhillWiggins Then we will need to see actual code to know anything about the issue.

Comment: Thanks @hvaughan3 I've added my object class and my database class used for creation of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

i have same issue. [i install this package for sqlite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/data-access/using-sqlite-orm) and set targeted version to android 8(oreo) my application works again